# Configure cloud service providers

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, cloud-storage

I purchased a Windows 10 PC for testing. I don't use third party cloud service providers, so I would like to completely remove OneDrive. I have my own personal cloud, so I would like the Operating System to use my local installation of OpenStack.

I tried to remove OneDrive via the control panel, but its not listed. I also tried right clicking and ***`Uninstall`***, but the option is not available. I found a [tip using the PowerShell](http://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/), but the removal failed.

I also failed to locate information on switching to my cloud service provider. Confer, ["windows 10" change cloud service providers site:microsoft.com](https://www.google.com/search?q="windows+10"+change+cloud+service+providers+site:microsoft.com).

How do I:

- completely remove OneDrive from this Windows 10 machine
- configure the operating system to use my OpenStack installation

Answer (score 0):

> How do I completely remove OneDrive from this Windows 10 machine?

It does not appear to be possible to actually remove OneDrive from Windows 10. There are three different ways to do so.

> Option 1: Unlink OneDrive on Windows 10
>
> 1. Right-click on the OneDrive icon in the notification area and then select "Settings".
> 2. Click "Unlink OneDrive" on the "Settings" tab.
>
> Option 2: Disconnect your Microsoft Account from Windows 10
>
> 1. Click the Start button, type "settings", and then click the "Settings" app.
> 2. Click on "Accounts" and then click on "Your account".
> 3. Select "Sign in with a local account instead" and follow the instructions through the prompts.
>
> Option 3: Disable through Group Policy
>
> 1. Type "group policy" in the Cortana search bar and then select "Edit group policy".
> 2. Browse to *Local Computer Policy* -> *Computer Configuration* -> *Administrative Templates* -> *Windows Components* -> *OneDrive*.
> 3. Right-click on the "Prevent the usage of OneDrive for file storage" entry and select "Edit".
> 4. Choose "Enabled" and then select "OK".

<sup>Source: [How to Completely Disable OneDrive](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/wiki/odoptions-oddesktop/how-to-completely-disable-onedrive/b97a8336-62e7-476c-872c-3286c0a01cf6)</sup>

> How do I configure the operating system to use my OpenStack installation?

This should be as simple as installing Horizon and configuring your machine, following the supplied instructions to sync your files to your OpenStack instance which you currently have set up.

I should point out that Windows 10 does not have a native way to sync files to any cloud provider without a third-party client. While the OneDrive functionality cannot be uninstalled, it technically is still a client, and exists outside of the native functions of Windows 10.